# Using buttons in CSS, HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I can't figure out how to have a function refer to my button so that I can have my button actually do stuff when I click it. Here is my function:

```
this.Click = function () {
        alert('It works');
    }
```

Here is my button in the return statement:

```
<button id="button" onClick="Click()">Click me!</button>
```

Both of these are in a larger function. I keep getting errors about my Click() function and I don't know why!!
[EDIT] I'm in a .js file, not an html file

Comment: remove the "this." and it should somewhat work, though you really need to look into event binding in general, as there's fundamentally better ways. Event attribs (and mixed-case attribs in general) are somewhat frowned upon these days.

Comment: Please show the "larger function". Note that in order to use a function in the `onclick` attribute, it must be defined in the global scope. Unless `this` is `window`, the function is not global. In any case, using `addEventListener` is almost always the better choice.

Comment: Did you read the error? And did you search for adding a click handler to buttons with Javascript? There are many tutorials on this. It appears you are guessing at the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Please visit https://www.w3schools.com/ and try stuff before asking questions at stackoverflow i got this answer under 3min there

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "It works";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please supply more information if you can.
What you have currently works

```js
this.Click = function () {
        alert('It works');
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
  body{
    width:100%;
    background-color:tan;
  }
  #background{
    background-color:brown;
    padding:2%;
    border-radius:10%;
    width:10%;
    height:20%;
    margin-left:40%;
    }
    #button{
    background-color:tan;
    padding:2%;
    border-radius:10%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="background">
    <button id="button" onClick="Click()">Click me!</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this and it will work.

```
const $button = document.getElementById('button')
$button.onclick = function() {
  console.log('clicked');
}
```

If you want to use on HTML, you need to create the function **Click** on the js file. Should be like:

js file:

```
function Click() {
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

html file:

```
<button id="button" onclick="Click()">Click me!</button>
```